# D3 Visualization Questions

Tags: javascript, d3.js, visualization

I'm working on a visualization and working off of a jsfiddle I found on stackoverflow.

I haven't done D3 before, so I had a couple of questions.

I want to visualize some json like this

```
{word:"cat", count: 30},
{word:"dog", count: 15}....
```

I've been working on a jsfiddle here

http://jsfiddle.net/matthewpiatetsky/nCNyE/3/

1. How can I ensure that text and circle don't intersect? The previous fiddle ensured this for the circles, but I want to prevent the label for one circle from intersecting with other circles/other labels.
2. How can I change the size of circles to scale relative the amount of open space in the window? I'm thinking I'll make a 800 by 800 window, and if there's lots of empty space and few circles, I want circles to get bigger, and if there isn't i want them to get smaller.

Any tips would be much appreciated, thank you!
(I know I can figure this stuff out myself, and I am doing so slowly, but some examples of how to do these things that I could play around with would be helpful!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JwQP6/3/ This is a way to scale the circles by the size of the window. I'm using jquery's `.height()` and `.width()` method to find the height and width of the document, then scaling each circle by whichever is smaller divided by 100.

Comment: Thanks. This isn't 100% what I was looking for since they intersect, but it is helpful. However, I realized I could just remove the circles and only visualize the words. Do you know how I would just visualize the words and change their color and size like i'm doing for the circles? thanks!
or the other alternative seems to be to put the text in the center of the circle

Comment: Have you seen this? https://github.com/jasondavies/d3-cloud

Comment: i haven't but that looks very helpful thank you! I haven't decided yet if i want to use circles or just words, but I'll take a look at that

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/AYvZP/6/

Comment: uh i don't see anything showing up, though that does look interesting, looks like you added the text visualization thing, but like i said don't see anything showing up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer for your first question is that you can't do this automatically with D3. You can try to ensure that this is the case by manually checking the positions of the labels and circles, or by using something like D3's force layout to lay them out automatically without overlap. Either of those options would be quite a bit of work though and in the second case you would have no guarantee that nothing would overlap.

Concerning your second question, you determine the size of the window and set the radius accordingly, e.g. something like

```
var radius = Math.sqrt(window.innerWidth * window.innerHeight) / 100;
```

Comment: Thanks, both answer were helpful, though not 100% what I was asking. For the first case, this is possible for nodes but not for labels? If so, would the best course of action be to put the labels inside the nodes? For the second case, that is pretty cool, but I was actually thinking about determining radius to fill up the window with circles based on the total radius of other circles, not based on the window size (if there's 10 circles with radius 5 each circle will be bigger than if there are 100 circles with radius 10)

Comment: There's nothing to automatically avoid overlap in D3. And for your second question you can easily multiply your factor (100 in my example) by the number of circles before using it for the division.

Comment: thanks, the second is a good idea. and aren't force and charge used to prevent overlap? I just added more text so the force isn't working properly, so I'm trying to figure out how to use force with a function of the radius (i saw this on some blog, but haven't figured out how to use it yet)

                    
charge: (d) -> -Math.pow(d.radius, 2.0) / 8